# How is @RequestMapping implemented to support flexible signatures

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

As we already know, the handler method which are annotated with `@RequestMapping` are allowed to have very flexible signatures, and in arbitrary order. So we may have methods like the following in a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld")
public String helloworld(){
    ...
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld")
public String helloworld(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
    ...
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld")
public String helloworld(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ...
}
```

Spring can always find the correct method to call and pass the correct parameters. I would like to know the implementation behind the scene, could someone explain to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At startup, Spring uses reflection to scan through your `@Controller` methods for those annotated with `@RequestMapping`. It registers the corresponding `Method` instances. It creates an internal map-style data structure so that it can match a request URL with a handler method.

In parallel, it constructs a `List` (of sorts) of [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) instances. These are strategy objects. Spring has an implementation for each [supported parameter type](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

Once it has the handler method, it gets all its parameter types. It loops through the list of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s, checking if the current `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` supports the parameter type. If it does, it uses it to resolve a value to be used as an argument. If it doesn't, it moves on to the next one. If none can do it, Spring throws an exception. It collects all these values. Spring finally calls `invoke` on the `Method` object with the collected argument values, in order.

Comment: So the spring always has to loop through the list or map to find the method to call for each request? There seems to be some overhead.

Comment: @DinoTw That's the only way to do it (more or less some intelligent ordering) so that you can restrict the matching based on all the attributes you can provide in `@RequestMapping` (headers, paths, path variables, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

it's fairly simply mechanism. first of all methods are listed using reflection. then each method with this annotation (spring uses many different annotations) are processed by some kind of controller processor. and again using reflection spring checks each parameter one by one. if the parameter has type defined in some map or collection, object of that type is selected from the spring context and put into into an ordered collection of parameters. when spring scans all parameters and find all objects to pass to that method it executes that method with prepared parameters - again by reflection.

ps. if you don't know how it works try to write similar functionality by yourself. it's really simple

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try some reflection myself.